# xslt sum with a node based calculation?

Tags: xml, xslt

I'm generating a html file off a received xml file, and I'm trying to get the sum of what would be values calculated per node level for instance if I am provided with xml like

```
<Header>
    <Row Type="TypeA" LineQty="20" LinePackQty="10" ></Row>
    <Row Type="TypeB" LineQty="30" LinePackQty="3" ></Row>
    <Row Type="TypeA" LineQty="18" LinePackQty="6" ></Row>
</Header>
```

I currently do at node level

```
Number Of Packs <xsl:value-of select="number(@LineQty) div number(@LinePackQty)" />
```

and a total section

```
Total Qty <xsl:value-of select="sum(Header/Row[@Type='TypeA']/(@LineQty))" />
```

Those are okay but if I try something like

```
Total Packs <xsl:value-of select="sum(Header/Row[@Type='TypeA']/number(@LineQty) div number(@LinePackQty))" />
```

I'm getting errors with a few variations I have tried.

For the example xml above there would be two nodes of interest which would be

20 / 10 = 2

18 / 6 = 3

So I'm looking for the total number of packs as 5

Is there some way to do this inline or do I need to pre-process the received xml to calculate a PackQty per Row node first and then sum it as I have done for LineQty?

Comment: The answer depends on which version of XSLT your processor supports. In XSLT 2.0, you can sum calculated values directly; in XSLT 1.0, you need to do two passes.

Comment: I'm using c# .Net 4 so looks like two passes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try it along these lines:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:exsl="http://exslt.org/common"
extension-element-prefixes="exsl">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/Header">
    <!-- FIRST PASS -->
    <xsl:variable name="Rows-rtf">
        <xsl:for-each select="Row[@Type='TypeA']">
            <Row LineQty="{@LineQty}" LinePackQty="{@LinePackQty}" Packs="{@LineQty div @LinePackQty}"/>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:variable>
    <xsl:variable name="Rows" select="exsl:node-set($Rows-rtf)/Row" />
    <!-- OUTPUT -->
    <output>
        <xsl:copy-of select="$Rows"/>
        <total-qty>
            <xsl:value-of select="sum($Rows/@LineQty)"/>
        </total-qty>    
        <total-packs>
            <xsl:value-of select="sum($Rows/@Packs)"/>
        </total-packs>  
    </output>   
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

---

Applied to your input example, you should get:

**Result**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<output>
  <Row LineQty="20" LinePackQty="10" Packs="2"/>
  <Row LineQty="18" LinePackQty="6" Packs="3"/>
  <total-qty>38</total-qty>
  <total-packs>5</total-packs>
</output>
```

---

Note that some Microsoft processors use a different namespace for the `node-set()` extension function.

Comment: ah, that works when it is output xml, when I try to convert to html it does complain about namespace "exsl"

Comment: I don't think the output method plays any role here.